# Angular 2 do not run change function on creation

Tags: angular, typescript, onchange

I have the problem that my change function is called when data from service arrives the first time.

Therefore I tried to set a flag. But NgOnContentInit sets the flag too early.

How can I prevent my change function to be called on creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the change function in `ngAfterViewInit.` it will load the your change function after all methods called.

Comment: Oh! It should work,I am also using in my project as like your requirement,try to use Set time out method.

Comment: the problem was that I took the change function of a colorpicker. If I take the change function of angular itself it works =)